# How to create a list of separate dictionaries which are not all the same

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to create a list of Dictionary.
I am not getting the desired output.
Here is my code:

```
list = ['Frank','John', 'Mitchel','Melania','Samson','scophield']
dict = []

for i in list:
    name = {}
    for i in list:
        name["First_name"]= i
    dict.append(name)

print(dict)
```

As Output,I have this:

```
[{'First_name': 'scophield'}, {'First_name': 'scophield'}, {'First_name': 'scophield'}, {'First_name': 'scophield'}, {'First_name': 'scophield'}, {'First_name': 'scophield'}]
```

I am expecting something like this:

```
  [{'First_name': 'Frank'}, {'First_name': 'John'}, {'First_name': 'Mitchel'}, {'First_name': 'Melania'}, {'First_name': 'Samson'}, {'First_name': 'scophield'}]
```

How can I get the desire output?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need iterate twice, just do one time

```
list = ['Frank','John', 'Mitchel','Melania','Samson','scophield']
dict = []

for i in list:
    name = {}
    name["First_name"]= i
    dict.append(name)

print(dict)
```

Output:

```
[{'First_name': 'Frank'}, {'First_name': 'John'}, {'First_name': 'Mitchel'}, {'First_name': 'Melania'}, {'First_name': 'Samson'}, {'First_name': 'scophield'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
namesList = ['Frank','John', 'Mitchel','Melania','Samson','scophield']
namesListOfDicts = [{"First_name": i} for i in namesList]


[{'First_name': 'Frank'}, {'First_name': 'John'}, {'First_name': 'Mitchel'}, {'First_name': 'Melania'}, {'First_name': 'Samson'}, {'First_name': 'scophield'}]
```

Comment: Thanks you all for your comments I am very grateful